# How to create custom actionbar in android?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I want to create custom actionbar in android,
this is my simple code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        menubar();
    }

    public void menubar(){

        ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        View mCustomView    = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_bar, null);
        ImageButton button  = (ImageButton) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.bt_menu);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    }

}
```

but when running it displays error like this :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setCustomView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
        at dot.com.coba.MainActivity.menubar(MainActivity.java:39)
        at dot.com.coba.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, please read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) Android Developers Blog post.
Note, that now, you should use `Toolbar` instead of `ActionBar`.

> In this release, Android introduces a new Toolbar widget. **This is a
>   generalization of the Action Bar pattern that gives you much more
>   control and flexibility. Toolbar is a view in your hierarchy just like
>   any other, making it easier to interleave with the rest of your
>   views**, animate it, and react to scroll events. You can also set it
>   as your Activity’s action bar, meaning that your standard options menu
>   actions will be display within it.

In other words, the `ActionBar` now became a special kind of `Toolbar`. This is an excerpt from [Google's official Material Design spec document](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar).

> The app bar, formerly known as the action bar in Android, is a special kind of toolbar that’s used for branding, navigation, search, and actions.

---

How to setup `Toolbar` in your project?
**1).** In your `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

**2).** Extend your `Activity` from `AppCompatActivity`:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
```

**3).** Create link to your `Toolbar` as *class member* of `Activity` or use `ViewHolder` pattern:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    //Some code

    private Toolbar mActionBarToolbar;

    //Some code
}
```

**4).** Create new method `getActionBarToolbar()` in `MyActivity`

```
protected Toolbar getActionBarToolbar() {
    if (mActionBarToolbar == null) {
        mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        if (mActionBarToolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
        }
    }
    return mActionBarToolbar;
}
```

**5).** Override method `setContentView` of `MyActivity`:

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    getActionBarToolbar();
}
```

**6).** Create file `res/layout/toolbar_actionbar.xml`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    myapp:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
    myapp:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:background="@null"
    myapp:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBar.TitleText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize" />
```

And **set your values** to properties `myapp:theme`, `myapp:popupTheme`, `myapp:titleTextAppearance` or **remove** it.

**7).** Include in layout of your activity(for me it `layout_my_activity.xml`):

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar_actionbar" />
```

**8).** Run your project.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create your Own Actionbar then hide The Default Actionbar. put this line in Your Activity

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

and Create Your Own Layout in Xml file , like i created below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibBack"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/back_1"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:text="Activity name"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: *Output of xml Layout*]

That's it now just Set title as your requirement and you can call backpress event in imagebutton click-listner easily

Sound like Easy ! hah

Answer (score 0):

Your `getActionBar()` method returns null, so try with `getSupportActionBar()` like this:

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Comment: i try like that, but cannot work,
cannot resolve method 'getsupportActionBar'

Answer (score 0):

```
    mContext = mAppCompatActivity.getBaseContext();
    ActionBar mActionBar = mAppCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar();
    ActionBar.LayoutParams mParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(mContext);
    mFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(mParams);
    if (mActionBar != null) {
        mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setCustomView(mFrameLayout);
        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) mFrameLayout.getParent();
        mToolbar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        mToolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
    }
```